# FormControl's valueChanges doesn't trigger when new value set

Tags: angular, rxjs

It is very weird that valueChanges doesn't trigger in below example. Is this a bug ?
Do I have to unsubscribe from valueChanges?

```
subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;

constructor() {

    this.form = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(0, { validators: [] })
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let sub = this.id.valueChanges.subscribe((value: number) => this.tokenSelected(value));

    //Value changes doesn't trigger because of this line 
    //but it works if I remove it. 
    this.subscription.add(sub);
  }

  get id() { return this.form.get('id')!; }

  setId() {
    this.id.setValue(1);
  }
```

Comment: Try initializing your `subscription` with `new Subscription()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is very weird that valueChanges doesn't trigger in below example. Is this a bug ?

It's not a bug and `valueChanges` doesn't trigger because it's already unsubscribed within `ngOnInit`.

The issue is with the below assignment:

```ts
subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;
```

It creates a new Subscription and sets it's `closed` property to `true`. The `closed` flag is used to indicate whether the Subscription has already been unsubscribed.

When you add a new subscription using `add(sub)`, it internally checks if the subscription is already closed and since the `closed` property was set to `true`, the newly added subscription `sub` is automatically unsubscribed. Hence  the `valueChanges` didn't triggered in your case.

Instead you can have the initialization as below:

```ts
subscription = new Subscription();
```